# Why does updating an app clear its defaults?

Tags: android

Let's say you have an app that declares itself able to handle a system intent like Phone and that the user selects it as the default app. When the market updates the app, why does it clear the defaults? Is there a way to prevent that, so if I wanted Dialer 1.0 to handle the phone button, Dialer 2.0 will still do it without me having to re-select it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The defaults map to specific implementations in the application (the name of the class implementing an activity), which can change when an application is updated.  To be conservative and safe, the platform has traditionally cleared those when an application is updated because they may change and result in a reference to an activity that no longer exists.  There is nothing you can do in your app to prevent this from happening.

Comment: But at install time, you know the list of Activities the new APK provides, and what the previously-set defaults are. So shouldn't it be possible to retain the defaults, where the target Activity still exists?

Comment: It's possible for it to be smarter, but currently it is not.